# cv.MclustDA() error: Error in data[-folds[[i]], , drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r

I'm using the mclust() package for R to classify a univariate dataset, then assign classifications to new data using the Discriminate Analysis functionality. When trying to calculate the cross validation error rate using cv.MclustDA() I keep getting an error. Below is the code and error. The model object works fine, but something isn't right with doing the cross validation on that model object. Can anyone shed any light on what this error is? It's obviously failing based on the `nfolds=` argument, but changing the number doesn't help.

```
> DA_mclust_AmazData_3group=MclustDA(data=Combined_AmazData[,4], class=Combined_AmazData[,13])
> summary(DA_mclust_AmazData_3group)
------------------------------------------------
Gaussian finite mixture model for classification 
------------------------------------------------

MclustDA model summary:

 log.likelihood  n df  BIC
           -Inf 29 18 -Inf

Classes  n Model G
      1 12     E 4
      2  8     X 1
      3  9     E 4

Training classification summary:

     Predicted
Class  1  2  3
    1 12  0  0
    2  0  8  0
    3  0  0  9

Training error = 0 
> 
> cv.MclustDA(DA_mclust_AmazData_3group)
cross-validating...
  |                                                                                  
|   0%Error in data[-folds[[i]], , drop = FALSE] : 
      incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: I communicated with the administrator for this package. This was a bug in handling of the univariate case. It is fixed in the next package and will be up on CRAN soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The administrator for the Mclust package got in touch with me. This was a bug in the handling of the univariate case and will be fixed in the next version, which should be posted to CRAN soon.